# npm hangs on npm install -g appium

Tags: node.js, npm, appium

Trying to install appium on a OSX Virtual Machine.
Command I'm using is `npm install -g appium`

```
VM-AUTO:lib vm1$ npm -v
3.7.2
```

When doing so it just hangs on loadRequestedDeps → netwo

Attached is url to a GIST of the verbose output where it is hanging.

https://gist.github.com/nuggit32/f19dc8e213d6c27961ea

I don't see any error to research on in the verbose output, so not sure what the problem is.  Any help on debugging this would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I needed to change the network adapter to be on my ethernet lan connection for this installation to download and install.  Smaller packages worked on the virtual network connection, but this was a big package with a lot of dependecies.